# How do I open Android's tombstone files in Ubuntu?

Tags: android, android-ndk

I need to read tombstone files, but I didn't find any way to do it on Ubuntu. What are some (preferably stand-alone) programs to do it?

Comment: Please check this link, it will help you understand how to ask a good question. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Android-tombstones](https://github.com/feichh/android-tombstones) is python script to retrieve line info from an android tombstone using "ndk-stack" and "addr2line".

I haven't had a chance to try it by myself, but I think it is what you need.